# How to make my number turn positive/negative based of D/C column?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a proper formula in excel that will allow my number to turn positive/negative based on a drop list containing Debit and Credit option. (ex. In cell B7-B45 I have a drop list for choices Debit and Credit only. In cell E7-E45 is the amount column. So lets say the user types in an amount in **"E7"**, I want that number to change to a **"negative"** if they choose **"Credit"** from the drop list. But, if they choose **"Debit"** from the drop list the number they typed in remain **"positive"**.)

Comment: This question is off topic for this site as it is not a programming question.

Comment: I agree with Joe that this is not a "Whats wrong with my code" question. As a discussion to get OP started, unless you have a helper column you are going to need to use VBA. If you use VBA then use the worksheet change event to detect changes to cells in the drop downs (I assume its data validation) in the B column and column E. Then depending on the value in B it would change E to +/-ABS(Value in E). Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thank you @nbayly yes the drop down is data validation. I will try it that way and see how it turns out.

Comment: Why not doing the opposite? Simply have "debit" in B if `>0` and credit if `<0`... this way no extra check would be need (also you would not have to select what to do)... just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add an additional column? Then this would be my suggested solution:

```
=IF(B7="Credit",-1*E7,E7)
```

[image]

If you cannot add a column, I would write a small macro such as:

```
Sub CheckValue()

For i = 7 To 45
    If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Credit" Then
        If Sgn(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value) = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value * -1
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's my dilemma it can only be one amount column and I don't think it's possible formula wise. I did it the exact same way you did but that's not the format they are looking for. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I tried locking the formula that way I could still change the value if need to be and not have the formula erase but that was impossible as well. Is there another way to get what I need?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a macro. I have added a piece of code of how I would solve it. It needs to be run after all amounts in column E have been entered.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries Tiffany.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:-
=-(num)
Examples:-
=-(-1) Outputs: 1
=-(1) Outputs: -1